# What does "max. 3% of bank" stand for in Cookie Clicker?

Tags: cookie-clicker

The description for the Bakeberry seed on Cookie Clicker says that the extra 30 minutes of CpS that you can get is capped at "3% of bank". What is it referring to? 3% of the bank CpS? If that is so, it would always be capped because 30 minutes of bank CpS is smaller or  equal than 30 minutes of the total CpS. That's confusing.

[image: bakeberry_seed_description]

Comment: In the general sense, "bank" always means "the current number of cookies you can spend"; as long as you remember this, you'll do fine.

Comment: The naming is confusing because there is a building called a Bank, as well as Stock Market upgrade offices called banks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Fandom Wiki](https://cookieclicker.fandom.com/wiki/Garden#Bakeberry):

> Additionally, it's important to note that bakeberry harvesting rewards are capped at just ***3% of your current cookies***, so they should ideally only be harvested when you have loads of cookies saved up to get a bigger reward. (In order to get the full reward from all your bakeberries, you'd need to have at least 16 hours 40 minutes worth of CpS sitting there in your bank.)